# Difference between Smarty and SmartyBC classes

Tags: php, smarty

just a quick and brief question but what is the difference between Smarty and SmartyBC classes? why am I only loading one.. what does the other one do? its just the similar file name that made me ask, is there any difference at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SmartyBC is a **B**ackwards **C**ompatibility Wrapper.

If i remember correctly it allows `{php}` and `{include_php}` inside templates.
Both tags were dropped with the Smarty 3.1 release, but a lot of software still uses them. That's why the BC class was introduced.

Or viewed from the other side: `{include_php}` is deprecated from Smarty and one would use a registered plugins to properly isolate presentation from the application code.

So, if you have an old system using these tags, you would have to use the `SmartyBC.class.php` instead of the normal `Smarty.class.php`.